# Jquery adding active class to all divs but only want the active one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to set the active div based on the url showing.

This code works fine for everything that isn't the index.  On the index it puts the active class tag to all the divs.  [Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5s7jrvgj/)

```
.navigation a.active-link {
    background-border: #red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: solid white;
    color: black;
    padding:10px;
}
#navigation a {
    line-height:26px;
}
#navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  text-overflow: clip;
  height: 26px;
  padding-bottom:26px;
}


 <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
   <a href="/">Show all</a>
   <a href="/ab/domains/" >.ab</a>
   <a href="/ac/domains/" >.ad</a>
   <a href="/ad/domains/" >.ac</a>
 </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$('#navigation').find('a[href$="' + pathname + '"]').addClass("active-link");

 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your index is `/` and since you add the class to all links whose `href` attributes ends with the current `pathname` (*which is `/` and all your links end with `/`*) it makes sense.

In the example you have provided you could target the elements that are equal to the path name and not ending-with

```
$('#navigation').find('a[href="' + pathname + '"]').addClass("active-link")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my pages:
Add a class home to your index link and you must use 'index' word in its href.

```
<a href="/index">show all</a>
```

then this:

```
        var curruntLocation = window.location.href;
        var linkFounded = false;
        $('#navigation a').each(function ()
        {
            var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
            if (curruntLocation.indexOf(thisHref) > 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass('active-Link');
                linkFounded = true;
            }
        });

        if (!linkFounded)// we are in index page
        {
              $('a.home').addClass('active Link');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You can Use the direct descendant combinator (>) to select the div you wish to add the class to.

An example is:

`jQuery('#nav li > a');`

You can assign ids to your a

I'm not so much a jQuery guy but I hope that helps